# How can I use to two MySQLi queries in separate for each statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use a row from a MySQLi result within a secondary query.
but im getting some unexpected results.

```
<?php 

$mysqli = new mysqli('connection');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);}

$today = date("Ymd");

$query = "SELECT course FROM dailytips WHERE date = 20130724 GROUP BY course"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{
    $rows[] = $row; } 
    foreach($rows as $row) 
    { 
        echo $row['course'] . "<br/>"; 
        $query2 = "SELECT horse, time, date FROM dailytips WHERE date = 20130724 and course ='{$row['course']}' ORDER BY time"; 
        $result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

        $today_uk = " " . date("d/m/y");
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) 
        {
            $rows2[] = $row2;
        }
        foreach($rows2 as $row2)
        {
           $date = $row2['date'];
           $date = date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));

           echo '<div style= "width:600px; font-family:verdana;"><div style="float:left; width:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top10px;">'.$row2['time'] . "-" . $row2['horse'] .' </div>' ;                         
        }
    }

$result->close();
$mysqli->close(); 

?>
```

my page currently looks like -

```
ipswich
11:00-running
12:00-flamingo rider
14:00-lightning                  

norwich
11:00-running
12:00-flamingo rider
14:00-lightning
13:10-ed is back
14:05-redrum
17:05-pickle
```

whereas I want

```
ipswich
11:00-running
12:00-flamingo rider
14:00-lightning 

norwich
13:10-ed is back
14:05-redrum
17:05-pickle
```

to be returned.

How can I free the result in the second for each query?

Comment: please make efforts to indent your code... this is *not* a detail

Comment: Sure, I can do this.  Is there reference to how it should be indented? I'm self taught and never been too sure!

Comment: @EdWright There's a couple main styles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good heavens what a mess.
Try this.

```
<?php 

$mysqli = new mysqli('connection');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);}

$today = date("Ymd");

$query = "SELECT course FROM dailytips WHERE date = 20130724 GROUP BY course"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$row = $result->fetch_array();

echo $row['course'] . "<br/>"; 
do {

    $query2 = "SELECT horse, time, date FROM dailytips WHERE date = 20130724 and course ='{$row['course']}' ORDER BY time"; 
    $result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);

    $today_uk = " " . date("d/m/y");

    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) 
    { 
        $date = $row2['date'];
        $date = date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));

        echo '<div style= "width:600px;font-family:verdana;"><div style="float:left; width:400px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;">'.$row2['time'] . "-" . $row2['horse'] .' </div>' ;                         
    } 

  } while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() );

   $result->close();
   $result2->close();
   $mysqli->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: wait, I'm not so sure about this. Are you certain you can cross 2 recordsets that way?

Comment: Give it a try and see

Comment: This gives me a blank page :-/

Comment: @EdWright What is the data type of your `date` column used in `where date = 99999999`

Comment: @EdWright Ok, I may have assumed to much when I changed the select to use the date generated by `$today = date("Ymd");`. I guess you dont have data on the database for all dates, so I changed the code back to use your hardcoded `date = 20130724` in the select statements. Try it again now. I also fixed a bug in the css ` margin-top10px;` changed to ` margin-top:10px;`